# "Ерь" и "ер"

Tags: алфавит

Почему   буквы "ерь" и "ер"  по реформе 1918 года получили неуклюжие названия "мягкий знак" и "твёрдый знак", в то время как названия других букв, наоборот, упростились: *буки - бэ, слово - эс* и т. д.?

Answer (score 1):

Ох, как же тяжело обычно давать ответ на вопрос, начинающийся с "Почему"...
Вас же заведомо не устроит ответ "Так решили", а ведь он единственно правильный. Просто решили отказаться от "тяжелого наследия царского режима" - и правильно, кстати,  сделали. Не по причине идеологической правильности, а по той простой причине, что исторические названия букв давно перестали ассоциироваться у большинства населения с чем-то понятным, обиходным.

На самом деле "новые" названия букв - не плод усилий исключительно победивших комиссаров, сама идея разрабатывалась наряду с орфографической реформой (тоже незаслуженно приписываемой исключительно большевикам) еще в Российской Империи начиная, наверное, с 1904 г. Первая мировая война не дала закончить эту языковую перестройку, но большевики ударными темпами её провели.

Но даже это - только конец истории "новых" названий букв, ибо на протяжении почти всего XIX фактически функционировали две азбуки (по названиям букв). Старая использовалась главным образом в классических гимназиях и церковных школах (я где-то уже писала, что в Российской Империи было как минимум пять принципиально различных типов начальных школ), в заведениях же низшего типа, для крестьян и простонародья, чаще использовали именно "новую" азбуку. Церковная с небольшими изменениями сохранила древнейшие названия букв, возникновение которых - интереснейшая глава истории языка, но здесь я не берусь её излагать. Изначально такие названия были либо основанных на греческих аналогах, либо представляли собой слова современного Кириллу и Мефодию языка или более позднего, но к XIX веку они окончательно превратились исключительно в названия-обозначения, непонятные невладеющим церковнославянским языком. Вторая же, "новая" азбука была основана на чисто фонетическом принципе, аналогичном используемому во всех европейских языках, названия были максимально приближены к звуку, этой буквой обозначаемому. Так они гораздо легче запоминались учениками из простонародья. Именно эта вторая, "гражданская" азбука и легла в основу современных названий.

Интересно, что названия "ер" и "еръ" первоначально были сохранены в этой новой азбуке наряду со "знаками", в алфавитных таблицах частенько приводились оба названия (одно из их - в скобках), такой вариант азбуки встречался в изданиях аж до 60-х годов. Но в конце концов закрепилось современное название как единственное актуальное.

(+) ------------------- 30.05.2015
Обратил внимание, что в текст попали "незакавыченные" цитаты, *"где-то я уже писал**а**"* - это явно не мой текст, я ни тут, ни "где-то" о таком не писа**л**. ))) Видимо издержки самой первой версии движка, с которой я не мог освоится. Как теперь править - не знаю.

Опечатки поправил, грамматику - не надо. "Невладеющий" - термин, можно спорить, применим ли он тут, но пишется он слитно. На принципе, **аналогичном**, а не "аналогично". И прочее.

Comment: Может, конечно, названия букв короче стали, а души нашу азбуку лишили... Не переломились бы детишки названия букв запомнить.

Comment: А смысл?  
Можно и на иероглифы перейти, тоже не переломятся.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, согласен с Вами. Пропал некий оттенок сакральности у неё, и превратилась азбука в обычный инструмент.

Comment: @Пересвет Остался бы у азбуки оттенок сакральности - глядишь и побоялись бы ее использовать для надписи "туалет не работает".

Answer (score 0):

не только детишкам запоминать, но и всем остальным.